# Argument variables in C

Tags: c, variables, arguments

I am writing a method that takes in a number n and n ints(a variable number) and this function will return the sum of the ints not including n. I am stuck on how to access each paramater individually. Here is what I have so far, I read about it online and hopefully I am on the right track. 
method that seem to be useful found on the net are:

```
va_start()
va_arg()
va_end()


int sumv(int n, ...)
{
  va_list list;
  int sum = 0;
  while(n>0)
  {
    //*********************
    //this is the part where I am stuck on, how do I get each paramater?
    //I know it will be an int
    //*********************
    n--;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you read [bobobobo's post on "How to use va_list"](http://bobobobo.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/how-to-use-variable-argument-lists-va_list/)

Comment: Hoorrah! for self-promotion :D ...lol :P .. Actually quite nice :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should look something like this:

```
int sumv(int n, ...)
{
  va_list list;
  va_start(list, n);
  int sum = 0;
  while(n>0)
  {
    sum += va_arg(list, int);
    n--;
  }
  va_end(list);
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: So it will go to next arguement when I call va_arg(list,int)? very Interesting

Comment: @JamesCarter: Yes (provided the next item is an `int`, anyway -- the second parameter is the type of the argument to retrieve).

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

int sumv (int n, ...) {
    va_list list;

    int sum = 0;

    va_start (list, n);
    while (n-- > 0)
        sum += va_arg (list, int);
    va_end (list);

    return sum;
}

int main (void) {
    printf ("%d\n", sumv (5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the sum of the first five natural numbers, `15`.

The basic idea is to `va_start`, giving both the list to use and the final argument in the function before the variable arguments begin.

Then, each call to `va_arg` gives you the next argument of the type specified (`int` here). This particular code calls it based on your counter but you could equally use a sentinel value at the end such as a negative number, provided that negative numbers aren't valid in the arguments.

Then, once you've processed all the arguments, use `va_end` to terminate the processing.